# urlpatterns += (static(settings.STATIC_URL,ducoment_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT))

Tags: django, python-3.x, url

Why do we use this line in **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns += \
    (static(settings.STATIC_URL,ducoment_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT))
```

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development), it says that the helper function `static()` is used to serve static files during development if you don't have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

The docs I linked give a short overview, and a bit more detail can be found in [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development); I think they are quite understandable.

Note: it is not for use in production, only for development.